# How KeyListener reactivates components?

Tags: java, keylistener

I want to deactivate components when something is pressed inside a textfield and reactivate them when you erase everything there and it becomes empty. But this doesn't seem to work:

```
idTF.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {    
        char ch = e.getKeyChar();

        if (Character.charCount(ch)>0) {
            searchF.setEditable(false);
            rangeTF1.setEditable(false);
            rangeTF2.setEditable(false);
            ageTF.setEditable(false);
            addressTF.setEditable(false);
            crimebox.setEditable(false);
            countrybox.setEditable(false);
            genderbox.setEditable(false);
        } else if (Character.charCount(ch)==0) {
            searchF.setEditable(true);
            rangeTF1.setEditable(true);
            rangeTF2.setEditable(true);
            ageTF.setEditable(true);
            addressTF.setEditable(true);
            crimebox.setEditable(true);
            countrybox.setEditable(true);
            genderbox.setEditable(true);            
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: On a side note: You should put all your hide/show logic into a void function and pass a boolean `hide/show` to said function.

Comment: `Character.charCount(…)` cannot ever equal `0`. It tells you how many `char`s are needed to represent a given Unicode code point – in your case, the one key that was actually *pressed* – which can obviously never be less than `1` for any actual character. You're never checking the contents of `idTF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper code modified is this:

```
class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        System.out.println(e.getType());
        searchF.setEditable(false);
        rangeTF1.setEditable(false);
        rangeTF2.setEditable(false);
        ageTF.setEditable(false);
        addressTF.setEditable(false);
        crimebox.setEnabled(false);
        countrybox.setEnabled(false);
        genderbox.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        if(idTF.getText().isEmpty()){

        searchF.setEditable(true);
        rangeTF1.setEditable(true);
        rangeTF2.setEditable(true);
        ageTF.setEditable(true);
        addressTF.setEditable(true);
        crimebox.setEnabled(true);
        countrybox.setEnabled(true);
        genderbox.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    }


}
```

Thanks @Maroun Maroun

Answer (score 1):

You can have a [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html):

```
DocumentListener documentListener = new DocumentListener() { 
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
     enableOrDisable(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        enableOrDisable(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        enableOrDisable(arg0);
    }   

    private void enableOrDisable(arg0);(DocumentEvent arg0) {
        //Code to enable/disable button
    }
};
```

And add this listener to the fields you want:

```
myComponent.getDocument().addDocumentListener(documentListener);
```

Comment: That worked! thanks! my only problem now is that if I don't erase everything with backspace but I select all and CTRL+X (Cut) the componetnts are not getting enabled.....

Comment: in document listener how can I allow ONLY numbers?

Comment: You should use [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).